# "dump" entire data model as one big table in an excel sheet

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I work with Power Query & Power Pivot. I load several tables in the data model of Power Pivot thanks to Power Query. Then I create relationships between those entities.

Now that the tables are linked with each others, is it possible to benefit from it and dump the whole data in a sheet? I must allow the users to see the whole thing in a table, not just summaries with pivot tables.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/583083/925350) and [this add-in](https://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/the-unpivot-add-in/)

Comment: without macros if possible :)